# How to redirect to 404 if no data from external API (universal React + Redux app)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router

I have a route with params and I want to **render/redirect to a 404 route if** an action returns **no data from** an **external API**. What would be the most sensible way to do this?

This is the router:

```
    export default (
        <Route path="/" component={App}>
            <Route path=":venueName" component={Venue} />
            <Route path="*" component={NotFound} />
        </Route>
    );
```

The Venue component is connected to Redux and fires a action:

```
// ...
componentWillMount() {
    this.props.actions.fetchVenue(this.props.id);
    // want to redirect to 404 if this returns success === false
}
// ...
```

Action looks like this:

```
export const fetchVenue = (id) => ({
    type: 'FETCH_VENUE',
    payload: axios.get('http://someAddress/api/venues/id'),
});
```

The problem I have here is how do I figure out to do this with server-side rendering and for any amount of routes. I'm using "match" from react-router in express to render the markup. Please me know if you want me to post more code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The component isn't the right place for this kind of logic, IMHO. I do this in my action, and use `react-router`'s `browserHistory. So something like:

```
export function fetchBrand(id) {
  return function(dispatch) {
    fetchData(`brands/${id}`, {
      headers: { 'X-Token-Auth': localStorage.getItem('token')}
    }).then(response => {
      dispatch({
        type: FETCH_BRAND_SUCCESS,
        payload: response
      });
    }).catch(err => {
       if (err.response.status == 404) {
          browserHistory.push("/my404page");
       }
    });
  }
}
```

And I'd have some sort of `route` to `my404page`, for example.

Comment: It works, thank you! This method will require me to do a .catch() for every route that has params. Is this ok or does it seem like too much effort? 

This is what I'm using to trigger the push: https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-redux#what-if-i-want-to-issue-navigation-events-via-redux-actions

Comment: I don't think I can answer that question. You _always_ want to deal with errors, so unless you can come up with a global `axios` error catching method, I'd say you should do this.